# openstack: changing scheduler_max_attempts nova.conf does not affect anything

Tags: openstack, openstack-nova, nova-scheduler

I want to reduce `scheduler_max_attempts` in `nova.conf`. I changed it and restarted `nova-scheduler` service. Then I tried to test the change by triggering multiple vm creation at the same time. I could see that there are more number of retries happen than I set for `scheduler_max_attempts`. I want to know if any other service needs a restart to apply scheduler_max_attempts change. Does anyone have idea about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that I have to restart `nova-conductor` service to apply changes in `scheduler_max_attempts`.